# Conditional merging of lines of Characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a question in notepad++ like this;

```
123. The airplane will not land in time
if weather is not clear due to rain and storm. Are you acceptable to re
turn the flight? (the question is splitted into 2 or 3 lines)
a yes
b no
c. yes but refund money
d. we will risk and land
```

I want the above question to be made in a single line. all the questions will start with answer choice "a". As there are more than 100 questions CTRL+J would be very difficult to apply on every question.

Need Your suggestion please.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1481711/763386) and add expected result formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

- find what: `\r\n(?!(\d{3}|[a-z])\.? )`
  *(depending on your OS you might need to remove `\r`)*
- replace to: "" *(nothing)*
- make sure "regular expression" is checked

This works whether you have a dot after the letter ("c.") or not ("a")

Test is here: https://regex101.com/r/4WKuA9/2

[image]

Comment: This will not work if you have multiple blocks. It will join the last answer and the first line of the next question.

Comment: Hi Mate Juhasz, Thanks for your suggestion. It absolutely works... Awsome!...... But a small issue.... It merges the next question with the last option of the last qustion. In my question I am not using question numbers (as Q. No. 123 in the example given).  The result looks like "d. we will risk and land 123. The airplane will not land in time.........." Any suggestion to break the next question?

Comment: Exactly as Toto told... It joins the last answer and the first line of the next question.

Comment: Hi Juhasz, Your solution gives me 99% result but for the small issue as said above It joins the last answer and the first line of the next question. A small refinement in the regex would help me to get 100% expected result. Any modifications you can suggest, please.

Comment: @RajkumarJanarthanan: I've updated the expression, it works with multiple blocks now.

Comment: Nope... The issue is still the same. It still merges the last line and the first line of the next question.

Comment: Can you add an example of multiple blocks to your question? So I would be able to test it.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^\d+\.|\G).+\K\R(?!^[a-z]\.?\h)`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # start non capture group
  ^             # beginning of line
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    \.          # a dot
  |             # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)               # end group
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!             # neagative lookahead, zero-length assertion that makes sure we haven't after: 
  ^             # beginning of line
    [a-z]       # a small letter
    \.?         # an optional dot
    \h          # 1 horizontal space
)
```

**Given:**

```
123. The airplane will not land in time
if weather is not clear due to rain and storm. Are you acceptable to re
turn the flight? (the question is splitted into 2 or 3 lines)
a yes
b no
c. yes but refund money
d. we will risk and land
123. The airplane will not land in time
if weather is not clear due to rain and storm. Are you acceptable to re
turn the flight? (the question is splitted into 2 or 3 lines)
a yes
b no
c. yes but refund money
d. we will risk and land
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123. The airplane will not land in time if weather is not clear due to rain and storm. Are you acceptable to re turn the flight? (the question is splitted into 2 or 3 lines)
a yes
b no
c. yes but refund money
d. we will risk and land
123. The airplane will not land in time if weather is not clear due to rain and storm. Are you acceptable to re turn the flight? (the question is splitted into 2 or 3 lines)
a yes
b no
c. yes but refund money
d. we will risk and land
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: This is awsome.... A biggggggggg..... thanks to you. I was struggling to get this.... Excellent... Thanks.

Comment: @RajkumarJanarthanan: You're welcome, glad it helps. But why did you unmark my answer and prefer the other one that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Toto, Excuse me for unmarking it... your solution is really great. But a small issue is it was not merging lines, in between  two questions i.e. if an answer of particular choice of a or b runs for two or three lines, whereas in other case it merges that too... However, in both the cases there are small issues need to be refined. I wanted to mark both but unfortunately I can mark only one. Im sorry to do that.

Comment: @Toto, All I could do it upvote your answer and give you an honest appreciation! Good work

Comment: @Prasanna: Thank you.